# Count Collisions in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

So, I have a list of `GameObject` named boxes, and I need to count collisions of elements from that list in `Update()`, like:

```
void Update()
{
    int collisionNumber = boxes[0].CountCollisions;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you talking about counting the contact points? Maybe this would help: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collision-contacts.html

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially write a small script for each type (box) that requires it's collisions to be counted with [Collider.OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html)

```
public int countCollisions = 0;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision hit)
{
    if (hit.gameObject.name == "Cube" )
        countCollisions++;
}
```

Attach that to **each cube** in your list (via AddComponent() possibly) and call the value of countCollisions recursively.

```
int totalCollisions = 0;
for (int i = 0; i != boxes.Length ;++i)
{
    totalCollisions += boxes[i].countCollisions;
}
```